# Migration of Access and reporting services from SP 2010 to SP Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, migration, access-services

I have a requirement to migrate existing Access service on SP 2010 On Prem server to SP 2013 Online, how should I do it?

Can I edit the existing access service in Access 2013 and then republish it in SP Online?

Comment: How many tables do you have?

Comment: May be 10 tables are there...

Answer (score 0):

You can export the tables in Access to SharePoint Online.

Right-click on the table and select Export -> SharePoint List -> Enter SharePoint URL

I don't think there's a way to do the entire database at once, so you'll need to do each table.

Reference: http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/export-an-access-table-to-a-sharepoint-online-list.html